# Unwanted gap between squares in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, viewers

I was using tikz to create a pixel art. When I view it in Texstudio everything is alright and looks as desiered. However in my OS' pdf viewer (Mac Preview) its not the same thing. Dependent on the scaling there you can see lines between the squares. Is there something I can do about this other than changing my pdf viewer?

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \fill [fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \fill [fill=black] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \fill [fill=black] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);
    \fill [fill=black] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How it should look like (and does with the built in Texstudio pdf viewer):

[image]

How it looks like in Mac Preview (note the thin gap):

[image]

The squares would actually have different colors. (So I can't just draw one square.) This is just a minified example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are viewer issues. Not sure if anyone ever solved them completely.

Comment: Use `\filldraw` with a very small `line width`. `0.1pt` whould be enough to trick the renderer. Yes, the squares are going to overlap. But no, no human eye can tell if one square is `0.1pt` greater than the other.